# How to get rid of some parts in a string variable?

Tags: r

The original string is like this "965 - Vehicle parking area", how do I get rid of the "965 - " part in R? (There are two spaces before and after the dash.)
Thank you!

Comment: [0-9-]+ Use Regex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possibility is to use gsub function to find the first ' - ' and remove everything before and also remove the dash with the space before and after that.

```
> tmp
[1] "965 - Vehicle parking area"
> gsub("^.*? - ","", tmp)
[1] "Vehicle parking area"
```

If there are two spaces:

```
> tmp <- "965  -  Vehicle parking area"
> sub("^.*?  -  ","", tmp)
[1] "Vehicle parking area"
```

Comment: Look at str_split in package stringr

Answer (score 0):

Use `str_replace` function in `stringr` library. You just need the alphabets and spaces between them, so this will work-

```
> str_replace("965 - Vehicle parking area", "[^A-Za-z]+", "")
[1] "Vehicle parking area"
```